# *Android Error*-Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

Tags: android

I'm new at this and is the first time I try to do an android app. I'm trying to do a rock, paper & scissors I know I haven't finish the code but I'm having some error....

Comment: Please edit your question to include some information about what the error is.

Comment: did you even try to compile it while writing it? The first error probably comes after System.out.println("It's a tie!");
else if (playerplay.equals("3")). You haven't closed your if statement (and some other else-if statements in this code)

Comment: Firstly you are using `setContentView(R.layout.main);` then agian `setContentView(tv);` :O.

Comment: There's a bunch of statements that leave out the "if" and/or "else" towards the end, at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few places that could be the problem, but one that could be causing you trouble is where you have

```
else (computerplay.equals("5"))
```

you are missing the `if`, you need something like

```
else if(computerplay.equals("5"))
```

in a few places.

Also, you need to reference the TextView that's in your layout, so instead of

```
 TextView tv = new TextView(this);
```

you need something like

```
 TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
```

and dont call setContentView(tv).

Comment: @MarSant you're welcome, dont forget to mark this as the answer :)

Comment: I changed the TextView from

TextView tv = new TextView(this);

to this

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

but it gives me the error of id cannot be resolved or its not a field

Comment: in your main.xml layout you need to have a <TextView ... id="@+id/textview" />.